# Automatically converting from tuple/array to struct... and back?

Tags: c++

I have an application where I am handed a `std::array<double, N>` where each double is a distinct (and more or less unrelated) parameter. Just for example, they could represent pressure, a distance and a safety factor.

As the number and meaning of these parameters might change over the course of development, I would like to convert this to a less error-prone representation before doing anything else - for example, a struct like this:

```
struct Params
{
  double pressure, distance, safetyFactor;
};
```

From there on, chances are low that anyone messes up.

Without further assumptions about struct layouts etc., `std::memcpy` is out of the question (and let's not even think about strict aliasing violations). Manually writing and updating conversion functions would be tedious and prone to introducing errors.

I noticed that you could automatically convert this array (and potentially any tuple) to a matching struct by combining brace initialization with parameter pack expansion:

```
template<class T, class Array, std::size_t... Is>
T toTyped_impl(const Array& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return { arr[Is]... };
}

template<class T>
T toTyped(std::array<double, T::Dim> arr)
{
    return toTyped_impl<T>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<T::Dim>());
}


struct Params
{
  static constexpr unsigned Dim = 3;
  double pressure, distance, safetyFactor;
};

Params foo()
{
    return toTyped<Params>({1, 2.0, 3});
}
```

The `Dim` member is not strictly necessary but is convenient here and also provides insurance against passing an array of the wrong size. Manually ensuring its correctness is easy.

**My question:**
Is there a way to go back from the struct to the array representation?

If not, is there another good way to convert from the double array to a more expressive type (that is unlikely to cause problems from changing the used parameters)? I considered indexing the array by enum values but it's suboptimal in every way (need to manually update conversion functions *and* the enum definition, and possibly also a collection of all these enum values)...

Comment: -- boost::fusion

Comment: @oakad Would you mind elaborating how you think this solves the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use meaningful getter

```
struct Params
{
    double pressure() const { return data[0]; }
    double& pressure() { return data[0]; }

    double distance() const { return data[1]; }
    double& distance() { return data[1]; }

    double safetyFactor() const { return data[2]; }
    double& safetyFactor() { return data[2]; }

    std::array<double, 3> data;
};
```

So you have both access.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a Fusion-adapted sequence:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Params,
    (double, pressure)
    (double, distance)
    (double, safetyFractor))
```